# Extract text between two characters with Xpath

Tags: php, regex, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

With Xpath, is it possible to extract text between two characters? And if Regex is required, is there a way to use Regex with the [import function](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=11318&answer=75507) of Google Spreadsheets?

If it is not possible in Google Spreadsheets, how would I be able to do it? (preferably with php)

I want to extract three strings within every div element and the strings are surrounded by different characters. When they are surrounded by certain characters, they should be extracted to one column in a csv file and when surrounded by other characters, they should be extracted to another column.

#### Example:

```
: text1. blabla is text2, dada and text3 is
```

I want to extract *text1*, *text2* and *text3*.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to make it clear whether you are talking about XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0, because both have very sizeable user communities, and the answer is very different in the two cases.

In XPath 1.0 you can use the substring-before() and substring-after() functions.

In XPath 2.0 you can use regular expressions, in the matches(), replace(), and tokenize() functions.

I'm afraid I know nothing about google spreadsheets or their import function.